# Best way to check if the record is exist

Tags: java, mysql

what is the best way to check if the user is exist

i have wrote this code

```
try{
PreparedStatment mPre=conn.preparedStatement(INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(?,?);
}catch(Exception e)
{
if(e.getMessage().contains("Dublicated"))
{
throw new Exception("user is exist");
}
}finally {
mPre.close();
conn.close();

}
```

my friends told me that this is stupid query 
and i should do like this

```
Statement stm = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM .......");
int cnt = rs.getInt("total");
```

Comment: can you paste the dotted portion of the select sql also?

Comment: Your way would insert the user if he does not exist.  Do you really want that?

Comment: yup i really want that 
i need to know why should check if user is already exist ?

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is right. You can check if row exists by query:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM *table* WHERE *something*)
```

Comment: i don't think so, why should i do search if user is exist ?

Comment: Something like `WHERE user_name = 'foobar'`

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to verify if the given username and password exists in your user table, you should use PreparedStatment because it will help you in protecting your application from SQL injection.

**But**

Inserting a new user to the database is not the right way to do user validation.

You can do something like this example:

```
 String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM USER_TABLE WHERE USER_ID = ? AND PASSWORD = ?";
 PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
 preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);
 preparedStatement.setString(2, "1234");
 ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL );
 while (rs.next()) {
     //You will need user information to render dashborad of your web application
     String userid = rs.getString("USER_ID");
     String username = rs.getString("USERNAME");    
 }
```

Complete code refrence: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Comment: i don't want to select userID, why should i ? what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: The code provided by me is just an example of how it should be done and you will have to modify it as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are trying to insert a row that breaks the unique primary key constraint of database tables AND the exception thrown has a stack trace that contains the word "duplicated" then your code should work fine.
 
 
But in the unlikely event that the stack trace changes and does NOT contain that word, your code won't work anymore.  
 
It's more likely that you are trying to insert a row with a unique primary key value but an existing username, which won't give you the error that you hope for.  That's the reason why it would be smarter/safer to retrieve results for that username and count how many results there are.

Comment: i don't care about the other exceptions i care just about that exception, i need to know what is the best way

Comment: The best way seems to be what your friend is suggesting.  Count the number of results from a query with the username you want to insert (you don't have to process any of them, just see how many of them there are).  If there are more than zero, then the user exists.  If there are zero, the user doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I still dont know why my query is faster  there is no reason to do another select statement

Comment: It comes down to this:  The way your friend suggested there is no room for error.  The way you are suggesting will work under certain conditions, but there is also room for error.  Do it your own way if you like, but don't complain if/when you get the wrong results.